# List<List<string>> To DatagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview, extension-methods

How do i convert a `List<List<string>>` to a DatagridView?

I know the below does not work...

```
List<List<string>> ExampleList = new List<List<string>>();

DataGridView1.DataSource = ExampleList;
```

So I was thinking I could write an extension method...

```
public static DataGridView ToDataGridView(this List<List<string>> lstr )
        {
            DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

            return dgv;

        }
```

It's the code in between ...

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
```

and...

```
return dgv;
```

That I am unsure about.

Comment: Normally you would like to bind a List<> to a DataGridView. May I kindly ask what your purpose is in doing this?

Comment: Just convert that structure into a `DataTable` and use it as a `DataSource` for the `DataGridView`. Also take a look over [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11331388/3602352) it will help you convert from your jagged list to a `DataTable`.

Comment: Why don't you convert your list to DataTable and assign this datatable to gridview?

Comment: [How to bind `Object[,]` into datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236282/how-to-bind-object-into-datagridview)

Comment: It would be just two lines of code: 1: `dgv.ColumnCount = list.Max(x => x.Count());` and 2: `list.ForEach(x => dgv.Rows.Add(x.ToArray()));`. See the linked post.